# How to display the correct page number in the rows to repeat at top of an Excel sheet so that they adapt when printing on multiple pages

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel document containing a sheet spanning multiple A4 pages. I have set up some rows to repeat at top, that indeed repeat on each A4 page when printing.
A cell of these top rows contains the page number and number of pages. I compute the number of pages using a VBA sub called each time we save the Excel document:

```
Sub Refresh_NumPages()
    NumPages = 0
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Visible = -1 Then
            j = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).PageSetup.Pages.Count
            NumPages = NumPages + j
        End If
    Next

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(14, 5).Value = "Page 1/" & NumPages
End Sub
```

Problem: page number is the same on each A4 page.

Question: how can I make the page number to adapt, the same way it does in an excel header, but in that particular cell

Exemple: let's say that I have my sheet spanning 4 pages (A4), on the first page the cell would contain 1/4, on the second page the cell would contain 2/4, etc.

Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: What's the reason for not using the header? (your current approach is not going to work)

Comment: Page number is included in a layout imposed by a customer, so we need control over where and how to display it, which was the reason we went for putting the page number in a cell

Comment: Then I think you're going to actually have to repeat those rows on the sheet itself, not via the print setup.

Comment: Following your idea to use headers, is there a way then to position a header field more precisely than just using the top margin? If i want to move it a bit further left for instance to overlap with the corresponding cell? Thank you

Comment: You'd have to pad with spaces until it's in the right location.

Comment: Ok, not ideal but does the job as long as top rows height are "locked" somehow and columns width too.Thanks